# cmake and make unable to compile YAP in Fedora 23

Tags: makefile, cmake, fedora-23, yap

This is kind of a specific question, but, I am unable to get cmake and make to compile Yet Another Prolog in Fedora 23.  Cloned the latest repo on Github, YAP 6.3.4.  My friend ran cmake and make successfully on the identical clone on his Funtoo Linux.  When I run them on Fedora 23, I get weird errors that would only make sense if CUDD headers were missing, but CUDD is installed with the header files.

I hope anyone has enough experience to offer a reason why a cmake-generated Makefile would fail to compile in one Linux system while compiling on another.

Here is a sample of the make errors (Makefile made with cmake with no errors).  The "unknown" type name is in CUDD headers which are installed on my system.  The source file cplint is supposed to be built using CUDD

```
% YAP 6.3.4-76638bb7 (compiled  2016-09-01T01:01:57@dhcp-129-8-62-64)

In file included from /home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint_yap.c:15:0:
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:41:3: error: unknown type name ‘DdNode’
   DdNode * * booleanVars;
   ^
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:54:3: error: unknown type name ‘DdNode’
   DdNode *key;
   ^
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:64:33: error: unknown type name ‘DdManager’
 variables createVars(YAP_Term t,DdManager * mgr, int create_dot, 
                                 ^
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:69:1: error: unknown type name ‘DdNode’
 DdNode * retFunction(DdManager * mgr, expr expression,variables v);
 ^
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:69:22: error: unknown type name ‘DdManager’
 DdNode * retFunction(DdManager * mgr, expr expression,variables v);
                      ^
/home/safulop/yap-6.3/packages/cplint/cplint.h:70:1: error: unknown type name ‘DdNode’
 DdNode * retTerm(DdManager * mgr,term t,variables v);
 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem cames from the CUDD library. You need to fix the include directory folders of CUDD in the Makefile...